# readthedocsサイトでビルドエラー（use_2to3、funcparserlib）

Tags: python3, sphinx, setuptools, read-the-docs

readthedocsでのドキュメント生成時のエラーについての質問です。
まだ公開を果たした実績がなく、慣れている人にはFAQレベルかもしれません。
よろしくおねがいします。

#### 質問

次のエラーの解決方法をご存知でしょうか。

funcparserlib0.3.5でエラーになるのですが、最新版にしようとするとエラーになって最新にできません。

どちらのエラーも、エラー発生時のコマンドをローカルで実行した場合はエラーになりませんでした。

#### funcparserがエラーになるパターン

docs/requirements.txt

```
funcparserlib
sphinxcontrib-seqdiag
sphindexer
```

エラー発生時のコマンド

```
/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/sphindexer/envs/latest/bin/python -m sphinx -T -E -b html -d _build/doctrees -D language=en . _build/html
```

エラー内容

```
Running Sphinx v4.2.0
loading translations [en]... done

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/sphindexer/envs/latest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sphinx/cmd/build.py", line 276, in build_main
    app = Sphinx(args.sourcedir, args.confdir, args.outputdir,
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/sphindexer/envs/latest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sphinx/application.py", line 237, in __init__
    self.setup_extension(extension)
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/sphindexer/envs/latest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sphinx/application.py", line 393, in setup_extension
    self.registry.load_extension(self, extname)
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/sphindexer/envs/latest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sphinx/registry.py", line 429, in load_extension
    mod = import_module(extname)
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/sphindexer/envs/latest/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/sphindexer/envs/latest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sphinxcontrib/seqdiag.py", line 26, in <module>
    import seqdiag.utils.rst.nodes
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/sphindexer/envs/latest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/seqdiag/utils/rst/nodes.py", line 16, in <module>
    from blockdiag.utils.rst import nodes
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/sphindexer/envs/latest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/blockdiag/utils/rst/nodes.py", line 21, in <module>
    import blockdiag.builder
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/sphindexer/envs/latest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/blockdiag/builder.py", line 16, in <module>
    from blockdiag import parser
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/sphindexer/envs/latest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/blockdiag/parser.py", line 42, in <module>
    from funcparserlib.lexer import LexerError, Token, make_tokenizer
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/sphindexer/envs/latest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/funcparserlib/lexer.py", line 80
    def match_specs(specs, str, i, (line, pos)):
                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Exception occurred:
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/sphindexer/envs/latest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/blockdiag/parser.py", line 42, in <module>
    from funcparserlib.lexer import LexerError, Token, make_tokenizer
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/sphindexer/envs/latest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/funcparserlib/lexer.py", line 80
    def match_specs(specs, str, i, (line, pos)):
                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
The full traceback has been saved in /tmp/sphinx-err-48idl7xv.log, if you want to report the issue to the developers.
Please also report this if it was a user error, so that a better error message can be provided next time.
A bug report can be filed in the tracker at <https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues>. Thanks!
```

#### funcparser 0.3.6 にしようとしてエラーになるパターン

docs/requirements.txt

```
funcparserlib==0.3.6
sphinxcontrib-seqdiag
sphindexer
```

エラー発生時のコマンド

```
/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/sphindexer/envs/latest/bin/python -m pip install --exists-action=w --no-cache-dir -r docs/requirements.txt
```

エラー内容

```
Collecting funcparserlib==0.3.6
  Downloading funcparserlib-0.3.6.tar.gz (30 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/sphindexer/envs/latest/bin/python -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-bhqpa4x3/funcparserlib_f25d7c3ca2944b4fa2fe2a73f18e2891/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-bhqpa4x3/funcparserlib_f25d7c3ca2944b4fa2fe2a73f18e2891/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-sbd_vxbh
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-bhqpa4x3/funcparserlib_f25d7c3ca2944b4fa2fe2a73f18e2891/
  Complete output (1 lines):
  error in funcparserlib setup command: use_2to3 is invalid.
  ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/cb/f7/b4a59c3ccf67c0082546eaeb454da1a6610e924d2e7a2a21f337ecae7b40/funcparserlib-0.3.6.tar.gz#sha256=b7992eac1a3eb97b3d91faa342bfda0729e990bd8a43774c1592c091e563c91d (from https://pypi.org/simple/funcparserlib/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement funcparserlib==0.3.6 (from versions: 0.3, 0.3.2, 0.3.3, 0.3.4, 0.3.5, 0.3.6, 1.0.0a0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for funcparserlib==0.3.6
```

#### 以上

Answer (score 0, accepted):

解決しました。

#### 経緯

エラーメッセージから「use_2to3」に注目して調べたところ、funcparserlib最新版（α版）で解決している情報が見つかりました。

- https://githubmemory.com/repo/vlasovskikh/funcparserlib/issues/70

> I've found that force-using the funcparserlib 1.0.0.a0 release has resolved this problem for me in my GithubActions-based CI pipelines that build Sphinx docs. (All these pipelines greedily upgrade to the latest available pip, setuptools, and wheel at the time of running.)
>
> This might also work for you until we get a new non-alpha release here.
>
> (For reference, see also issue #65)

docs/requirements.txt を次のように書いたところドキュメントがビルドできるようになりました。

```
funcparserlib == 1.0.0a0
sphinxcontrib-seqdiag
sphindexer
```

#### 雑記

恐らくですが、seqdiagをreadthedocs環境で使うようなことがなければ、この問題には遭遇しないと思われます。